# background-attachment:fixed в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, браузер, background

Добрый день! Вопрос риторический. Как мы знаем, свойство `background-attachment:fixed` в браузере Internet Explorer работает некорректно, а именно: при прокрутке страницы блок, имеющий это свойство, "прыгает". Это при условии, что высота блока 100%. Возможно ли с помощью javascript обмануть этот браузер? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что можете сказать по этому коду? Тестировал в ie11, вопрос решается. Во всех ли остальных версиях - не знаю. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
        $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {

            event.preventDefault();
            var wd = event.wheelDelta;
            var csp = window.pageYOffset;
            window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
        });
}
```